# Issue on Ordering Thumbnails in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I am trying to create simple slider for displaying latest product on the page using Bootstrap 3 at This <kbd>**[DEMO](http://bootply.com/111875)**</kbd>. I have 6 thumbnails in a gallery div which I would like to display only 4 of them in front view and slide to left to see two more. I used bootstrap

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

css to render a `display: inline-block;` list of my `<li>`s but I do not know why they are not fitting in one line and 2 last items displays at the buttom of the gallery box. BESIDES the first `<li>` looks taller (Even if I have only 4 `<li>`).
Now my questions are:

1 - Why The First item Looks taller than the rest?
2 - Why Items are not displaying in a line?
3 - Finally why the `overflow: hidden;` property in `.gallery` is not performing properly?
and here is my code:

```
.gallery {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    max-height:325px;
}

 <!-- About Section -->
 <section id="ft" class="cbp-so-section cbp-so-init">
    <div class="container cbp-so-side cbp-so-side-top">
        <h4>Latest Features</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="well gallery col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-2 col-xm-1">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="well"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="well"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="well"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="well"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="well"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="well"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing a bit with Firebug, I found that the issue here is because of the following rule:

```
.list-inline > li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

All the `.list-inline > li` elements have a `padding-left:5px` rule, expect the first child. Because of that missing padding in the first child, the `img` inside has 5px more width (because of the `max-width:100%;` rule).

If you set the width of the `img` in pixels, you will not have this issue.

Regarding the (2) question, the bootstrap grid system requires that in one row the number sum of the `col-sm-*` is 12. You need to change in from `col-sm-3` to `col-sm-2` to have all 6 items in one line.

Regarding the (3) question, I am not sure what exactly you are expecting to see.

**EDIT 2**: See this link for a CSS fix http://bootply.com/111878

```
.gallery {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    max-height:310px;
}
.list-inline img.img-responsive {
    height: 233px;
    width: 233px;
}
```

Comment: Hi codingstill, Thanks for your code I just tried it but nothing change same issues still there

Comment: I didn't post any code of my own, I am just explaining how the issue occurs. Try my edit to see if this is fixing your issue

Comment: Thanks , I thing I got it. but as I told you I want to keep only 4 of items inside the panel. If I change the col-3 to col-2 then I have all of them in the panel!

Comment: Oh I see, I updated my answer with a CSS fix, I hope this works out for you.